# Breakpad's dump_syms not working properly

Tags: c++, windows, symbols, pdb-files, google-breakpad

The thing is that I have been working with **breakpad** recently and I have some issue generating the "**FILE**" data in the **sym** file.

**In my sym file** :

```
FILE 46 c:\users\soorya-pt2570\desktop\project files\crashanalyserbackend\breakpad\simulatecrash\project\source.cpp
```

**The actual path to my source file** :

```
"C:\Users\soorya-pt2570\Desktop\Project Files\CrashAnalyserBackend\BreakPad\SimulateCrash\project\Source.cpp"
```

as you can see, **the path to my source file is converted to lowercase**. Any Idea on what's going wrong?

I used the **dump_syms.exe** available [**here**](https://github.com/google/breakpad/tree/master/src/tools/windows/binaries) for my **pdb file**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Windows file systems are usually case insensitive. For our internal use case I have a script that does a mapping of the file names from the case insensitive name that `dump_sys.exe` produces to the correct name. I'm not aware of any direct fix in breakpad itself. If you only handle the path on Windows it should actually not matter at all and you should not see any issues from the lower case file names.

Comment: but when I use the "dump_sym" Linux executable(for a Linux application to produce sym), it is able to produce the path to the source file with case sensitivity.

Comment: Nearly all Linux file systems are case sensitive.

Comment: so, to achieve what I want, I have to do it internally huh(using scripts). 
no other go?

Comment: At least that is what I do. It is actually just a few lines to create a mapping and replace the file names. I use https://github.com/mmohrhard/crash/blob/master/tools/process-symbols/process-file-list.py plus some additional tooling.